# Express JS different action for same param name in different routes

Tags: javascript, express

Given this general case for Express routes:

```
app.param('widgetId', loadWidget);
app.route('/widgets/:widgetId')
    .get(getWidget)
    .post(postWidget);
app.route('/container/widgets/:widgetId')
    .delete(getContainerWidget)
    .post(postContainerWidget);
```

Where **loadWidget** loads the widget and places it in the Request object.

Would it be possible to have a different param handler for the **container/widgets/:widgetId** route?

The containers route doesn't need the whole widget loaded just to add the Id to it's list. Whereas the widgets route would want the widget already loaded.

I'd prefer not to go about renaming the params because in larger scope it could get very overloaded.

Comment: What do you mean by different param handler ? why not just use `loadWidget.id` in your param (or return just the id from the `loadWidget` Method)? Unless I'm reading this wrong..

Comment: `loadWidget` would be a method that loads the whole widget. Removing a widget from a container would only require the Id which is passed as a param. So `DELETE /container/widgets/1234` would not need to load the widget.  It's a simplified case, but even still, it's better to avoid calling out to the database if it's not necessary. In a more complex case, `loadWidget` could be a much heavier function, possibly connecting to other services.

Comment: Couldn't you define another route then for the edge cases // particular overloads you're looking for ? You can also have conditional nested params too.. so for ex : `app.route('/container/widgets/:widgetId/:action') ` where `action` might relate to .. Well defined action which could be handled through a switch.. For example!

Comment: As far as I'm aware, anytime you have `:widgetId` in a route it will call the `loadWidget` function. `app.param()` is ignorant of which route the param is in, and that's the core issue I'm trying to tackle.  Using a different name than `widgetId` would work, but in a real environment that would lead to `widgetIdContainer` `widgetIdContainersDuplicate`, etc. etc. so that you'd have a different handler for each time you are using a widget Id

Comment: I see your point, I don't have a solution right now, but will keep an eye!